# OS X: how to make command-line script appear as helper application to handle mailto?

Tags: macos, emacs, emacsclient

I'm trying to configure Emacs as my preferred application when the user clicks on a mailto: link.

Emacs has facilities for this:

[emacs 23 on OS X: mailto links & calling compose-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796601/emacs-23-on-os-x-mailto-links-calling-compose-mail%29)

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MailtoHandler

and I'll do it by creating a shell script that then calls emacsclient ("emacs-mailto-handler" in the previous link).

Unfortunately, when I go to Firefox, Preferences, Applications, it doesn't recognize shell scripts. Instead it wants an OS X application bundle (at least that's what I surmise).

I thus could perhaps figure out how to turn a shell script into an application bundle or figure out how to arm-wrestle Firefox into recognizing a shell script. Help? Or should I be thinking about this the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the OS X Automator App to run the shell script, and save the  Automator Project as an App Bundle.

You can use that App Bundle as you would any other Application.

Comment: And that worked precisely as advertised. Thanks slomojo! Right on!

Comment: @ocodo Could you please provide an Automator's screenshot? It seems that's I can't pass arguments to the shell script.

Comment: managed to do it with AppleScript only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848223/creating-an-mailto-handler-app-on-mac-osx/54484455#54484455